# Do i need to install Xcode to use subversion or is there a SVN client already included in Mac

Tags: xcode, svn

Do i need to install Xcode to use subversion or is there a SVN client already included in Mac.

New to Mac and not sure if it includes a SVN client.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to install **some** SVN client on MAC, there is no built-in one. You can choose from range of clients (including XCode):

- [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)
- [svnX](https://code.google.com/p/svnx/)
- [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/)
- [Cornerstone](http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/)
- [RapidSvn](http://www.rapidsvn.org/)

Comment: Can i take the client out of Xcode or do i need to install the entire Xcode?

Comment: There is no *anymore*. I recall MacOS / OSX having svn client built-in in previous releases.